# Javascript XML from string

Tags: javascript, xml

I try to get nodes from a XML-string. For some reason, I can only get the first tag. Sure it's something trivial I'm overlooking but in other (non-concatenated) cases the txt2xml function works fine. Is it the fact that the string is concatenated?

To answer my own question here... it's not the concatenation. Leaving the first- and last tag out and only processing f also leaves .length=1.

```
function txt2xml(a) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var v = parser.parseFromString(a, "text/xml");
    return v;
}

function init() {
    var f = "<node1 key='firstkey'/>Some text here would be nice.<node2>Text for node 2</node2>";
    alert("<tag>" + f + "</tag>");  //gives me: <tag><node1 key='firstkey'/>Some text here would be nice.<node2>Text for node 2</node2></tag>

    var g = txt2xml("<tag>" + f + "</tag>");

    alert(g.childNodes.length);  //gives me 1...?
    alert(g.childNodes[0].nodeName); //gives me tag (makes sense). Any higher than 0 gives a blank. Also makes sense when .length=1
}
```

Why is g.childNodes.length = 1 and why can't I access `<node1>`? Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, the root has indeed only one child, `<tag>`. All the others are _descendants_. Have you tried `g.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeName`? That should (if there isn't any whitespace between tags) give you `node1`.

Comment: That doesn't give me anything.... :-(
I thought <tag> in this case _was_ the root? Then there should be 3 children (<node1>, #text and <node2>).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it...

It took me some time and effort but I've finally found the solution. Still puzzled about it but it works. It appears that `v` does return xml and *shows* the root but actually *isn't* the root. By setting `v` to `v.documentElement` it show the real root. The correct(ed) code would then be:

```
function txt2xml(a) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var v = parser.parseFromString(a, "text/xml");
    return v.documentElement;
}

function init() {
    var f = "<node1 key='firstkey'/>Some text here would be nice.<node2>Text for node 2</node2>";
    alert("<tag>" + f + "</tag>");  //gives me: <tag><node1 key='firstkey'/>Some text here would be nice.<node2>Text for node 2</node2></tag>

    var g = txt2xml("<tag>" + f + "</tag>");

    alert(g.childNodes.length);  //gives me 3...!
    alert(g.childNodes[0].nodeName); //gives me node1 (makes sense). It's the first child of <tag>.
}
```